# export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to get the url of the backend, but I get an error while importing and it's not clear how to fix it.
warning  in ./src/store/index.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        backendUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1"
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
    getters: {
        getServerUrl: state => {
            return state.backendUrl
        }
    }
})

export default store
```

working `version`:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        backendUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1"
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
    getters: {
        getServerUrl: state => {
            return state.backendUrl
        }
    }
})

export default store
```

Comment: You're using vuex 3 which doesn't support Vue 3; I suggest using the `vue-cli` to generate a project for vue 3

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65779714/8172857

Comment: Boussadjra Brahim, i use this code and take this error: This relative module was not found: * ./App.vue in ./src/store/index.js  
although the path is correct xD

Comment: please share your `main.js`, `App.vue` and store content

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the vue-cli, I have found that the solution is to modify vue.config.js to include the devServer property.  See the [Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)

```
  module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api-ezbook': {
        target: 'http://localhost:80',        
        ws: false
      }
    },
    public: 'http://localhost:8080'
  }
  //  use to deploy
  publicPath: '/'
  //  use to deploy to live server
  //  publicPath: '/location/on/server'
  //  in production:
  //  publicPath: '/'
}
```